# Import from url

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

Imagine I had the file "module.py" on a webserver. I get the files contents by doing the following

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://example.com/module.py')
content = response.read()
```

The file "module.py" contains the function

```
def test():
    print("test")
```

What would be the best way to import the content so I could use the test function? I have seen a few solutions but they no longer seem to work.

Comment: Please don't do that. Loading and executing remote code is an incredibly bad idea. Especially over plain HTTP.

Comment: related: [How to import a module given the full path?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/67631/4279)

Comment: @ThiefMaster How so? and is there any safe way of doing it?

Comment: Why do you need to execute code from a remote location?

Comment: I need to use the code on multiple computers without having the file on every computer.

Answer (score 2):

So this seems to work for me

```
import wget
# url = url of the code, path = where you want it saved
wget.download(url, path)

import sys
sys.path.append(path) 
import module.py #this should be the name of the file that is downloaded
```

Answer (score 0):

Write down the content of `module.py` to a local py file. And then import it.

Answer (score 0):

In response to question on previous answer:

If you have the `module.py` saved to say, `local.py` file (in the same folder) you can just:

```
import local
```